# If cancellation laws hold, then a finite semi-group is a group

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

Show that if both cancellation laws i.e $w.a = w.b \implies a = b$ and $a.w = b.w \implies a = b$ holds then a finite semi-group (a finite set with associative binary operation) is a group.

I have seen some proofs which uses the alternative definition of group to prove it i.e. $a.x = b$ and $y.a =b$ have unique solutions for $x$ and $y$. I am not interested in such proofs.

How to prove this statement starting with cancellation laws and then showing that all axioms of group can be derived from them?

EDIT : As pointed out in one of the answer. This is only true when underlying set is finite. Edited accordingly.

Comment: See [Cancellable Finite Semigroup is Group](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Cancellable_Finite_Semigroup_is_Group) at ProofWiki.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks. This is what I have been looking for.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I did not know ProofWiki exists. You make my day.

Comment: I posted a proof of this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/137025/23211)

Comment: Thanks, @ymar. I like that proof. You make my day even brighter - I have something to think about what cancellation means.

Comment: @scaaahu Thank you, I'm glad my answer is useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint** $\rm\ \ \ell_a(x) = a\:\!x$ is $1\!-\!1$ so onto. So $\rm\:a\to \ell_a\:$ represents S as a subsemigroup of the finite group of permutations on S, which is [necessarily](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Tour%3aSubsemigroup_of_finite_group_is_subgroup) a group, since every element has finite order.

**Remark** $\ $ Notice how conceptual the proof becomes using this [regular representation (Cayley).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem) Exploiting these *structural* insights reveals the essence of the matter with minimal calculation.

Comment: When I tried proving the same when only one cancellation law holds, it all came to me as 'Buddhist surge of consciousness' ...

Comment: Can I get an example for non associative structure(loop), with cancellation law holds

Answer (score 4):

This is not true. The (strictly) positive integers under multiplication form a cancellative semigroup, but not a group.

Comment: Oops! I did not thought it through. I should have said 'finite set with ..'. I will now edit it.

Comment: Indeed, please see the definition  and the proof that a finite cancellative semigroup is a group here in Wikipedia[cancellative semigroup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellative_semigroup)